# nginx reverse proxy not working properly when specifying location

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am not able to make nginx proxy to work when specifying`location`

first I've tried to leave the location as `/` and it worked:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        location  / {

        resolver 127.0.0.1;
        allow "x.x.x.x";
        deny   all;
        proxy_pass http://consul:8500;
    }

}
```

If I look at the curl command `curl localhost -L -vvvv`

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Fri, 10 Jul 2020 16:24:38 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 39
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: /ui/
< 
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://localhost/ui/'
* Found bundle for host localhost: 0x557b754549e0 [serially]
* Can not multiplex, even if we wanted to!
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host localhost
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /ui/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Fri, 10 Jul 2020 16:24:38 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 7806
< Connection: keep-alive
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Last-Modified: Fri, 10 Jul 2020 07:37:44 GMT
< 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="ember-loading">
...
```

and I can see the html already. However, if I changed the conf file to this:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        location  /consul/ {

        resolver 127.0.0.1;
        allow "x.x.x.x";
        deny   all;
        proxy_pass http://consul:8500;
    }

}
```

and then try to call it like `curl localhost/consul -L -vvvv`, I get the following:

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /consul HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Fri, 10 Jul 2020 16:32:35 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 178
< Location: http://localhost/consul/
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://localhost/consul/'
* Found bundle for host localhost: 0x55ba7959f9e0 [serially]
* Can not multiplex, even if we wanted to!
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host localhost
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /consul/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Fri, 10 Jul 2020 16:32:35 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
```

I would appreciate any ideas on this issue

Answer (score 1):

When proxy a location you are adding this location to the request:

```
http://<your_server/consul/ -> http://consul:8500/consul/
```

other example (if proxy_pass http://consul:8500/test/ and location /consul/):

```
http://<your_server/consul/ -> http://consul:8500/test/consul/
```

If you want proxy **/** consul to *consul:8500/* you need remove the */consul* with a rewrite

```
location  /consul/ {
     resolver 127.0.0.1;
     allow "x.x.x.x";
     deny   all;
     rewrite ^/consul(.*) /$1 break;    #<---- This line
     proxy_pass http://consul:8500;
}
```